# Can a signature other than the serving default be specified in a Google Cloud AI Platform online prediction request?

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

`gcloud ai-platform predict` supports a `--signature-name` argument to specify a signature in a SavedModel: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/predict

The python SDK and the REST API for online prediction does not:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict

does anyone know how to get a prediction from a method associated with a signature other than the serving default in an online prediction setting?

I'd like to have one version of a recommender model handle a variety of tasks, each with different input features, while avoid having to create and deploy AI Platform "custom prediction routines."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature_name is specified as part of the JSON request:

```
{
  // If unspecifed default serving signature is used.
  "signature_name": <string>,

  // List of objects
  "instances": [
    {
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
      ...
    },
    {
      // Example 2
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
      ...
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```